# POST image from Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I need to post an image to a website. Iam able to capture the image using OV7670 camera module. But don't know how to store and post the image to a website. I didn't get any idea to start this. Can anyone help me to do this.
I got the image capturing code and circuit from
 https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/how-to-use-ov7670-camera-module-with-arduino

I have got the below components:

Arduino uno,
ESP 01 module,
OV7670

Comment: start by researching the different ways that pictures can be POSTed to a web server from a PC

Comment: @jsotola I cannot even post any data from arduino to a webpage using wifi module. Can you please give any idea to post any string data to webpage and the response back.